# No prometheus metric to find all unique label names, unique labels counts or unique label value pairs

Tags: prometheus

I was trying to create a high cardinality management dashboard as Grafana cloud has. See URL below:
https://grafana.com/docs/grafana-cloud/billing-and-usage/control-prometheus-metrics-usage/cardinality-management/

But I have found that there is no metric which can give me unique label names or count of unique labels or unique values for each label.

Is there any way to calculate these label details in Grafana?

Answer (score 0):

Prometheus provides [/api/v1/status/tsdb](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/api/#tsdb-stats) endpoint, which returns the needed information. Unfortunately I dont't know how to query this information from Grafana :(

P.S. Take a look [cardinality explorer](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/#cardinality-explorer) provided by VictoriaMetrics - probably it provides all the needed information for you.

Disclaimer: I'm the core developer of VictoriaMetrics.